# Where is the const CONFIG_KEY_PRODUCT_TYPES defined Magento2

Tags: magento2

Where is this defined? in Which config xml file?

```
const CONFIG_KEY_PRODUCT_TYPES = 'global/importexport/import_product_types';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is not defined in any XML file, as of [magento-2.1](/questions/tagged/magento-2.1), but the constant is not used either. So it could come from a partially implemented feature or a leftover that is not used anymore and has not been removed completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it inside core module of magento,

> magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php

Comment: I found that from that file only..It should be defined in some system xml rite? so wanted that path

Comment: this constant is not used anywhere in system. i have check it, what do you want to do using this constant, plz let me know?

Comment: ok cool, had doubt that it was declared anywhere in system.xml...clarified thx

Comment: I think this constant is useless in magento 2. coz they havent used in anyfile in whole system.

Comment: yes even i did a full search..its only declared as a constant in the above file